# defaultdict(list) concatenating all the values into one list

Tags: python, python-2.7, collections, anagram, defaultdict

What I am trying to do:

> Write a method to sort an array of strings so that all the anagrms are
>   next to each other.

I have the following code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
res = defaultdict(list)
L = ['foo', 'poo', 'k', 'fo', 'ofo', 'oof']

for w in L:
    res["".join(sorted(w))].append(w)
```

But now I want to take all the values in `res` and combine them into one list.

I tried this:

```
output =[]
for items in res.values():
    output.append(i for i in items)
```

But that gave me:

```
>>> output
[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x102a4d1e0>, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x102a95870>, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x102a958c0>, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x102a95910>]
```

How can I display the items in one list properly?

Desired:

```
['foo','ofo', 'oof','poo', 'k', 'fo',]
```

(all the anagrams are together, order doesn't matter as long as they are adjacent in the list.)

Comment: Can you update what you are expecting as the output? and what is `D` ?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do -

```
output.append(i for i in items)
```

You are actually appending the generator expression - `i for i in items` - into `output` list, as you can also see from the `repr` result of your `output` list. This does not automatically evaluate the generator expression and add the results. What you should have done was to use `output.extend()`. Example -

```
>>> output = []
>>> for items in res.values():
...     output.extend(items)
...
>>> output
['fo', 'k', 'foo', 'ofo', 'oof', 'poo']
```

This would evaluate the expression and append each element from the iterable (generator expression) to the list as a separate element.

---

But If you want to convert a single list from all the list values of `res` dictionary, An much easier way would be to use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable). Example -

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> output = list(chain.from_iterable(res.values()))
>>> output
['fo', 'k', 'foo', 'ofo', 'oof', 'poo']
```

Comment: Or just use a list comprehension right? `output = [ i for i in items ]`

Comment: I don't think so list comprehension would have been - `output = [i for v in res.values() for i in v]` .

Comment: @RobertB But I would still prefer `chain.from_iterable` . This is specifically what that is made for.

Comment: Note that `extend(i for i in items)` is just a strange way to write `extend(items)`.

Comment: Yea, correct, I just added that to point out that `extend` was needed instead of `append` . I still suggest `chain`.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

I believe that replacing

```
output.append(i for i in items)
```

with

```
output.extend(items)
```

will do what you expect.

Comment: This would append lists into `output` , not what the expected output would be. Also , this can be written as `output.append(items)` . No difference at all, since `items` is already a list.

Comment: This sort of works. It creates a list of lists like `[['k'], ['foo', 'ofo', 'oof'], ['poo'], ['fo']]`. I was looking for a single list, but this is good to know.

Comment: Edited, but the accepted answer already provides this solution.